# Что означает cлэш в css

Tags: css

Недавно при просмотре урока по верстке лендинга заметил вот такую запись:

`background: url(../img/first-bg.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;`

Далее нашет это: 
`border-radius: 35px 25px 30px 20px / 35px 25px 15px 30px;`

Что означает знак "/" в css и конкретно в данных примерах? Гуглил но особо не нашел по этой теме ничего.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В случае задания двух параметров через слэш, то первый задает радиус по горизонтали, а второй по вертикали (эллиптические уголки).

Тут: http://htmlbook.ru/css/border-radius